# How do you create an anonymous Python telnet connection?

Tags: java, python, windows, telnet

I am trying to telnet into a server using Python on Windows XP.  I can connect successfully by typing 'telnet HOST PORT' which creates an anonymous connection.  But Python's telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, PORT) returns 'Connection refused'.  Telnetting in Java also fails.  Spelunking shows that Python tries to create an anonymous socket connection.  My admin says he doesn't allow anonymous connections.  But neither Python nor Java allow authentication parameters to be passed in during socket connection creation (not that I could find).  Why does Windows' command-line telnet work when Python and Java both fail?  Any advice?

Comment: What exactly is an anonymous socket? I have never heard of that terminology.

Comment: Um, an anonymous connection using sockets.  One specifying only host and port; no username or password sent.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand the telnet protocol as a result of this response. Please read RFC 854, and note the lack of a formal authentication specification. (Authentication was specified in RFC 2841, but I have yet to actually see a field deployment of this outside of kerberized environments.)

Comment: Sockets don't have any authentication capability.  Higher-level protocols (like HTTP) do have authentication.  Sockets, however, are just sockets.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a good idea to trace both connection attempts (a failing case and a successful case) with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) or similar packet trace tool to see what the difference is at the protocol level.

Answer (score 1):

First, eliminate telnetlib as your problem:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("remote.host", 23))
```

If that succeeds, there is a problem in your usage of `telnetlib`, and we'll need to see an example. If it fails, then you have a basic networking problem, and Lance's suggestion of pulling out ethereal/wireshark is your next step.